# Unresolved push method because of strange type interfacing

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, geojson

I created a module like this:

```
module GeoJSON {    
    export interface position {
        (): number[];
    }

    export interface coordinateArray {
        () : position[];
    }

    export interface polygonRings {
        (): position[][];
    }

    export class GeometryType {
        public static Point: string = "Point";
        public static LineString: string = "LineString";
        public static Polygon: string = "Polygon";
        public static MultiPoint: string = "MultiPoint";
        public static MultiLineString: string = "MultiLineString";
        public static MultiPolygon: string = "MultiPolygon";
        public static MultiGeometry: string = "MultiGeometry";
    }

    export interface Geometry {
        type?: string;
    }

    export interface Point extends Geometry {
        coordinates: position;
    }

    export interface LineString extends Geometry {
        coordinates: coordinateArray;
    }

    export interface Polygon extends Geometry {
        coordinates: polygonRings;
    }

    export interface MultiPolygon extends Geometry {
        coordinates: polygonRings[];
    }

    export interface MultiPoint extends Geometry {
        coordinates: coordinateArray;
    }

    export interface MultiLineString extends Geometry {
        coordinates: polygonRings;
    }

    export interface GeometryCollection extends Geometry {
        geometries: Geometry[];
    }
}
```

When I use it I get a stupid error. That `push` is an unresolved method...

```
var lineString: GeoJSON.LineString = <GeoJSON.LineString> this._myGeometry;
lineString.coordinates.push(position);
```

I tried to cast coordinates onto `GeoJSON.position[]`. The code compile, but `JavaScript` throws an error:(

```
(<GeoJSON.position[]> lineString.coordinates).push(position);
```

How to make `push` visible in here? I can't change types of `coordinates` from `coordinateArray` to `position[]`, because later `JSON.stringify` will return different JSON data and server won't answer.

Comment: What is _myGeometry coming from? No amount of casting or changing the type information is going to make the method appear at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generics is still an [open work item](https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/185) for TypeScript.  So while you could have `position`, `coordinateArray` and `polygonRings` extend Array to know that the push method exists, the type would still never match.  Array in lib.d.ts uses a hacky _element which is handled specially by the compiler until generics are implemented.

You could copy over the definition of Array into `position` and replace all instances of _element with number, but that feels really ugly.  I would either replace all instances of `position` with number[] or give position x and y (and z) members.

Your run time problem is almost certainly that you never constructed `LineString` properly so `lineString.coordinates` is undefined.  Instead of casting to a `LineString` make the interface a class and set all the members in the constructor.  ie:

```
export interface position {
    x: number;
    y: number;
}

export class LineString implements Geometry {
    coordinates: position[];
    constructor() {
        this.coordinates = [];
    }
}

var lineString: GeoJSON.LineString = new GeoJSON.LineString();
lineString.coordinates.push({ x: 0, y: 0 });
```

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, when you write this:

```
export interface coordinateArray {
    () : position[];
}
```

What you're describing is a type with a *call signature*. The `()` means "you can call me with zero arguments", not "Here's what I am". The compiler is expecting you to use `coordinateArray` like this:

```
var x: coordinateArray = /* something */;
var y = x(); // y: position[]
```